# Compare two columns as date

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns in excel like column send out date & column received date. I want to compare each "**Send Out Date & Received Date**", if the difference is longer than 3 working day exclude Sunday then turn the "received date cells" will RED color.

```
[Send Out Date]          [Received Date]

   26-May                    28-May
   26-May                  **29-May**
```

Comment: Look into conditional formatting.

Comment: would you mind to show me how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel 2010:

- select the range you want to format (e.g. B2:B3 in your example)
- in home tab select conditional formatting - new rule - use a formula to determine which cells to format.
- type this: `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,11)>3`
- click format and set the formatting you need.

Comment: would recommend '=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2,B2,11)>ABS(3)', since it is difference

Comment: @Punith: good point, but I think here it isn't relevant (response date is not expected to be even less then sending date)